# How can I solve $u_t = u_x + u_{xx}$ on an isolated half-rod (Robin conditions)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem

This question seems so simple, yet the answer eludes me..

I'm trying to solve the advection-diffusion equation on the half-line x > 0:

$$ u_t = u_x + u_{xx} $$

The advection is in the direction of the origin. There is no flux across the origin, i.e., $u(0, t) + u_x(0, t) = 0$.

The equation represents the transient concentration of buoyant particles in the ocean. The first term is the buoyancy and the second one is the turbulent diffusion. $x$ is the depth below sea level and $x = 0$ is the sea surface.

Solutions are welcome of course, but any insight into the problem is helpful as well.

Comment: Did you try separation of variables?

Comment: Do you have an initial time condition as well? Without that I'd worry there's not enough boundary conditions, though one can just pick $u(x,0)=g(x)$ and proceed under that assumption.

Comment: Ideally I want the fundamental solution, i.e., the initial condition $u(x, 0) = \delta(x - k)$

Comment: Sorry: I realize my question is an almost exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507008/how-to-solve-robin-problem-with-general-initial-data-on-the-half-line?rq=1